# Open Jackson network with deterministic arrivals.

Tags: pr.probability

Dear Friends,

Is there any known Jackson-like theorem for an open Jackson network with deterministic arrivals?

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "deterministic arrivals" with some more detail?  Do you want to go away from a probabilistic Markov process to a deterministic process?  Are the times discrete?  Are the arrivals still poisson distributed or are the arrivals coming at fixed intervals?  Do you mean "fixed inter-arrival delays" for deterministic?  Also, explaining a bit more about queuing theory in your question and exactly what you're doing and why would also be helpful.

Comment: I mean the following: service time at every queue is distributed exponentially, and the external arrivals to the system are coming at fixed intervals (i.e., instead of Poisson($\lambda$), arrivals occur at fixed time interval of $\tfrac{1}{\lambda}$). The time is continuous.

Thank you.